# inserting a Dirac-delta function within the given integral.

Tags: mathematical-physics, dirac-delta

I am stuck in this question [given here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4SbJ.png) because I am facing a dilemma whether to insert a dirac-delta function within the integral (or not) and solve it, or there is some other method to do this problem.

[edit:- I still can't solve it. So, kindly can anyone let me know how to solve this question. I am really interested to know its solution.]

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Do you know how $\delta$ is defined? Do you know how limits of distributions are defined?

Comment: @md2perpe Sir, I have tried using all the properties or theories that I know but I still cant solve it.

Comment: Then please show how far you get.

Comment: Set $I_\epsilon = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\, u(x) f(x/\epsilon)/\epsilon\, dx$.
A change of variable gives $I_\epsilon = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\, u(\epsilon t) f(t)\, dt$. Then
\begin{equation}
I_\epsilon = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\, (u(\epsilon t) - u(0))f(t)\, dt
+ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\, u(0)f(t)\, dt.
\end{equation}
I'm guessing the author is arguing that, under the right conditions, the first integral tends to zero as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0+$. In that case you have $I_\epsilon \rightarrow u(0)$ which, it seems, is how he or she is making the equivalence to the delta distribution.

Answer (score 1):

I think the notion is that if the integral converges without any sort of regularization scheme, $f(x)$ must go to zero at $\pm \infty$. Then, you can show that the transformed function goes to zero at any $x \ne 0$ and it still integrates to unity. Those are the two defining characteristics of a Dirac delta function.

If you did have a regularization scheme like taking the integral over reals to be the limit of $\int_{-a}^{a}$ as $a \rightarrow \infty$ then I don't think the result is true any more, at least not without some further regularization.

Comment: Yes sir, I also feel the same. But sir, I still can't progress with this problem because I am unable to understand what shoulf i take to solve it.

Comment: Well, putting aside this issue of regularization, I think the whole problem is what I said, so if you feel the same you're done. To your more specific question, I wouldn't recommend inserting a Dirac delta function, I don't see how that would help.

Answer (score 1):

What you should show is that
for every $\varphi\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$ the following limit holds:
$$
\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\epsilon} f(\frac{x}{\epsilon}) \varphi(x) \, dx = \varphi(0)
.
$$

Using the substitution $x=\epsilon y$ we have
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\epsilon} f(\frac{x}{\epsilon}) \varphi(x) \, dx
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\epsilon} f(y) \varphi(\epsilon y) \, \epsilon\,dx
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(y) \varphi(\epsilon y) \, dx
.
$$

Here $\varphi(\epsilon y)\to\varphi(0)$ as $\epsilon\to 0.$ If $f\in L^1(\mathbb R)$ then, by [dominated convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem),
$$
\lim_{\epsilon\to0} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(y) \varphi(\epsilon y) \, dx
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \lim_{\epsilon\to0} f(y) \varphi(\epsilon y) \, dx
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(y) \varphi(0) \, dx
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(y) \, dx \, \varphi(0) 
= \varphi(0).
$$